# What sort of iron rod should I use in a magnetostriction oscillator?

Tags: transformer, oscillator, ultrasound, common-emitter, transducer

I'm trying to make a magnetostriction oscillator at home. Here is the circuit diagram:

[image: circuit diagram]

- 1 DC Power Supply
- 2 Ferromagnetic Core (Iron)
- 3 NPN Bipolar Junction Transistor (2N2222)
- 4 Capacitor C
- 5 Primary Inductor Coil L1
- 6 Secondary Inductor Coil L2
- 7 Reference Ground Node

So basically the magnetostriction effect results in the rod stretching and compressing, and the oscillator resonates at frequency F equal to:
[image]

(K is the length of the Iron Rod)

resulting in sound waves of the same frequency being generated. I primarily have the following questions:

1. Should the inductance of component 6, the secondary inductor be equal to that of component 5, the primary coil? How will this affect the working of the common emitter amplifier (component 3)
2. I'm planning to use a retort stand clamping the metal rod at its center. I'm targeting a length for the rod less than 25cm. Is there a particular radius/ area of cross-section of the rod. Will it affect the waves being produced??

Please let me know if I need to be mindful of any other practical limitations of this project while trying to implement it in reality.

Comment: Note that the [2N2222](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/296640.pdf) can only tolerate 0.8A collector current before it burns up.  These oscillators tend to use lots of power, so unless making a very small one, consider a transistor with larger current rating and a heatsink.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense!!

Comment: A video of an implementation with a  variation on that schematic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDPUv0zimnQ

Answer (score 1):

Although pure iron is weakly magnetostrictive, and could work in an oscillator, if you want to maximize the mechanical output, use other materials. [Design and Application of Magnetostrictive “MS” Materials](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.470.8061&rep=rep1&type=pdf), for example, which compares them with piezoelectric materials, and mentions the giant magnetostrictive effect in materials such as [Ni-Mn-Ga alloy](https://www.nims.go.jp/sfrg/magneto.html) and [Terfenol-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terfenol-D).